# JSF css with #{resource['']} makes NetBeans mark line as error

Tags: css, jsf, netbeans

I have a line like the following in my .css:

```
background-image: url(#{resource['gfx/logos.png']}),url(#{resource['gfx/background.png']});
```

And the above code works perfectly, but NetBeans 4.0 marks lines with #{} code in them as errors.  When I am using JSF that allows dynamic css, is there a way I can configure NetBeans to not consider these lines errors?  When I do introduce an error it makes it easy for me to be unaware of the error because of these false errors.

Comment: I don't do Netbeans, but what validation error exactly are you talking about? Usually just Googling the exact error message should give sufficient hints. Also, I wonder if it's an EL or a CSS validation error. If a CSS validation error (because those expressions doesn't look like URLs), how about just enclosing the entire expression in doublequotes like so `url("#{resource['gfx/logos.png']}")`?

Comment: Netbeans flags the file as invalid, which means if I ever introduced an actual error I might not notice until runtime.  It is a CSS validation error as Netbeans is not aware that there is a situation in which you can embed EL in CSS.

Comment: Okay. Theoretically, enclosing the EL in doublequotes could possibly fix this false negative. Let me know if it does that, then I'll repost it as an answer.

Comment: BalusC, if you post you answer below my self answer, I'll delete my answer and accept yours, since I answered myself based on your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the fact that this is actually a CSS validation error which is caused because the `url()` isn't in the right syntax for an URI, enclosing the entire EL expression in doublequotes should theoretically solve the problem.

Thus, so:

```css
background-image:
    url("#{resource['gfx/logos.png']}"),
    url("#{resource['gfx/background.png']}");
```